# Tomcat reload problem

Tags: tomcat, configuration

I am using Tomcat 6.0 in Eclipse 3.6,
every time when I modified a Java file,Tomcat will reload the whole Context. 
I wanna is there anyway to get rid of this.

while testing some function after login into my web application,If I changed some Java source file ,I need to login again and repeat my operation, it's painful.How can I avoid these ?

I have tried start Tomcat in debug mode, It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **reloadable** parameter in your Applications Context configuration. See [Context Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Adrian!But I dont think that's what I want.
when I modified a Java source file, tomcat detected changes and then reload the whole context so the HTTP sessions will be destoryed, It's a big trouble when testing.

Comment: Understood, but you can configure tomcat (via your context) to not reload by setting the reloadable to false. What is happening is that eclipse is auto compiling your source and dumping the class files to your tomcat webapps folder. By setting reloadable to false, tomcat will ignore the changes.

Comment: hi,Adrian!
while testing some function after login into my web application,If I changed some Java source file ,I need to login again and repeat my operation, it's painful.How can I avoid these .